# next.js protected route with context, "use client"

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js

I am trying to protect a page in next.js. Currently, the page re-routes to login before the current user's context can be accessed. I am using a separate loading state, as many other stack overflow posts have suggested. So, how do I fix the issue so that the user data from context can be viewed before everything renders?

app/profile/page.js

```js
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useUserContext } from "@/context/AuthContext";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

function ProfilePage() {
  const { user } = useUserContext();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    if (user == null) {
      setLoading(false); 
      router.push("/login");
    } else {
      getUserDoc();
      getPostedQuotes();
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);


if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <p>user from context: {user.username}</p>
 )
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you using token based authentication you shoud use the token instead of user. And simply store the token in local storage and on the context initilation load the token from the storage into the context if it is not expired.

Comment: I am using firebase auth. The data for the user is already in context, it's just not passed to this page quick enough so the reroute to /login triggers

Comment: Can you show the code where the userContext get the value?

Answer (score 0):

The order is incorrect for what you are trying to achieve, you need to first check whether user is null, then route to login if true, then setLoading to false. Like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    if (user == null) {
      router.push("/login");
    } else {
      getUserDoc();
      getPostedQuotes();
    }
    setLoading(false);
  }, [user]);
```

Comment: thanks for sending that over, but it is actually leading to the same issue. The page is still re-directing to login even when there is a user in the context.

Comment: Try it in an incognito/new session, also please report the react devtools screenshot as well, so that we can actually see what's going on